# How to Apply Condition for each Class using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several class which needs to be edited using jQuery unfortunately im unable to edit with just one statement, i hope that some on can help me how can i use either a .Each function or a looping where i can apply it for entire classes.

```
if ($(".A").hasClass("B")) {
$("<span id=\"Dummytext\">Condition 1</span>").insertAfter($(".N"));
} else if($(".A").hasClass("C")) {
$("<span id=\"Dummytext\">Condition 2</span>").insertAfter($(".N"));
} else {
$("<span id=\"Dummytext\">Condition 2</span>").insertAfter($(".N"));  
}
```

Comment: Both your `if` and `else if` have the same condition.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Also, your `if` and `else if` conditions are the same.

Comment: i want to loop this Jquery If and Else conditions.

Comment: @user3636823 You should try to tell us, what you **want** to do

Comment: @user3636823 BTW. If these are actual class names you use, you should rethink your class naming strategy.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LUY8q/

Comment: @HerrSerker - I would like to verify if the classes are different and inster some messages based on classes.

Comment: @user3636823 Your fiddle isn't referred to this question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LUY8q/

Comment: @HerrSerker - http://jsfiddle.net/LUY8q/21/

Comment: Your code is already the best solution.

Comment: The jQuery version in your fiddle is very old. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @HerrSerker but if you observe i have two calsses, B and C, but unfortunately only Condition 1 is getting applied, rather condition 2.

Comment: @HerrSerker - I updated to the latest version and still the old result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code: (as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUY8q/23/))
(Hint: the `$(this).each(...)` is the key point)

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    myDecide: function (classYes, ClassNo, selectorAfter, TextYes, TextNo, TextDefault, closestSelector) {
        $(this).each(function() {
            var after = $(this).closest(closestSelector).find(selectorAfter)
            console.log($(this))
            if ($(this).hasClass(classYes)) {
                $(TextYes).insertAfter($(after));
            } else if ($(this).hasClass(ClassNo)) {
                $(TextNo).insertAfter($(after));
            } else {
                ($(TextDefault).insertAfter($(after)));
            }
        });
    }
})



jQuery(".infoModule").myDecide(
    'inStock',
    'notInStock',
    ".ui-priceselector",
    $("<span id=\"messageinstock2\">Condition 1</span>"),
    $("<span id=\"messageinstock2\">Condition 2</span>"),
    $("<span id=\"messageinstock2\">Condition 3</span>"),
    '.searchrow-price'
  );
```

### Edit

Why did your code not work?

1. The `$(".A")` mathces every element with class `A`, but the `hasClass` function only works on the first object of the jQuery selection
2. With `$().each`you can help for 1. But then you face another problem. You always append the text to every `$(".N")`. YOu have to find the right `.N` relative to your `.A`. This is the `closest().find()` part.

Additionally I packed it into a jQuery function for your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
$(".A").each(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("B")) {
    $("<span id=\"Dummytext\">Condition 1</span>").insertAfter($(".N"));
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("C")) {
    $("<span id=\"Dummytext\">Condition 2</span>").insertAfter($(".N"));
  } else {
    $("<span id=\"Dummytext\">Condition 2</span>").insertAfter($(".N"));
  }
});
```

This checks for each element in the document that contains class `A`.

Comment: if ($(".A").hasClass("B")) {
    $("<span id=\"Dummytext\">Condition 1</span>").insertAfter($(".N"));
} else if($(".A").hasClass("C")) {
    $("<span id=\"Dummytext\">Condition 2</span>").insertAfter($(".N"));
} else {
    $("<span id=\"Dummytext\">Condition 2</span>").insertAfter($(".N"));  
}

Comment: The `if` statements remain the same, you just need to wrap it in the `.each()` and replace the `.A` with `this` like above. Fine, I'll edit it in the above code.

Comment: @undefined Absolutely, thanks for mentioning. @ OP you should consider changing the id to class.

Comment: When we run it is getting applied only for one such ID, but i have several ID with same class names, and which has class "C" as well.

Comment: @user3636823 er...could you please post the html?